# Do i need to normalize audio data?

Tags: audio, deep-learning, speech-recognition

I am applying deep learning algorithms to the [speech commands dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/speech_commands).
I am curious if normalization of the audio is needed before turning them into spectrograms or any other feature engineering thing?

I've gone through some notebooks on github that use this dataset and haven't found any clues, but as we use neural networks i think we need some normalization.
I have never worked with audio data so i am not very experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normalizing data is recommended for neural network training.
Good explanation here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458579/131706.